# Postgresql is the server running locally and accepting connection on Unix domain

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, psql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to install **postgresql-9.5** or **postgresql-9.6** on my ubuntu `16.04` or `14.04` machine, after following the installation process using below commands.

```
sudo apt-get install update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

But when I am trying to open `psql` from my terminal using below commands

```
sudo su postgres 
psql
```

every time its just showing.

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  Is the
>   server running locally and accepting  connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I have tried approximately 10 stackoverflow.com solutions but no success. Please help me out before I tear all my hairs :(

$ **service postgresql status**

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (**exited) since রবি 2017-03-12 21:45:56 BDT; 23min ago
  Process: 917 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 917 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
```

see this line carefully why exited ?  **Active: active (exited) since রবি 2017-03-12 21:45:56 BDT; 23min ago**

Comment: `active (exited)` is normal

Comment: First thing to check is the postgres logfile. Postgres fails to start up on (some) configuration errors, and reports this in the logfile, before exiting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can run the following command to check if postgresql is running:

```
service postgresql status
```

If PostgreSQL is not started you can start it with:

```
service postgresql start
service postgresql status
```

If it does not start properly, you can look at what is going on in the logs:

```
tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

You might have to run `createdb` to initialize a database (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html):

```
createdb demo
```

**Update**

If PostgreSQL is running when you do `service postgresql status` but you still can't connect, you should check if PostgreSQL is indeed running on port 5432 or another one with:

```
netstat -na | grep postgres
```

**Update 2**

Since the native packages on debian/ubuntu for PostgreSQL sucks, I advise you to install these instead: https://www.gab.lc/articles/install_postgresql_9-5_debian_ubuntu (replace `9-2` with `9-6`).

Comment: I added a port check to my answer, please let me know if it helps

Comment: netstat -na | grep postgres shows nothing on the terminal

Comment: ok I strongly advise you to remove the packages from debian and install the ones suggested in my "update 2"

Comment: Thank you! You saved me!

Answer (score 8):

This is how finally solved my issue after removing the existing postgresql version and directory

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-*
sudo rm -Rf /etc/postgresql /var/lib/postgresql
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

Comment: Straightforward answer that works. Thank you for writing.